# String slicing issue

Tags: python, slice

Right now, I'm trying to understand how string slicing works. In the example:

```
str='HELLO WORLD'
```

If I try `str[-2:1:-2]`, I get:

`LO L`

I thought I should get `LO LE` since we go backward until index `1`.

What is the problem with my reasoning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stop argument of slice notation is always exclusive.  Meaning, Python will slice up to but not including index `1`.

To get the output you want, make `0` the stopping point:

```
>>> 'HELLO WORLD'[-2:0:-2]
'LO LE'
>>> 'HELLO WORLD'[-2::-2]  # Equivalent in this case
'LO LE'
>>>
```

Comment: those two are only equivelent because its a step of 2 ... but yeah basically(+1)

Comment: True.  I actually put that to avoid people commenting *"the `0` is unnecessary here"*.  But it looks like I got the opposite. :)

Answer (score 3):

string slices end one before the last index ... regardless of iterating forward or backward

so if you wanted the output you put in your example you would need

```
my_str[-2:0:-2]
```

(and dont use `str` as a variable name)

Comment: 'str' is not a keyword in Python why shouldn't I use it ?

Comment: str is a keyword in python2 ... and it doesnt tell you anything about the variable... , variable names should largely be self documenting